# What is the different between RGBD-6D-SLAM and rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everybody, I see the ROS website RGBD-6D-SLAM [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM)
and
rgbdslam[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)
But I do not know what is the difference between the two.Which is easier to achieve. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44288/what-is--the-different-between-rgbd-6d-slam-and-rgbdslam/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first link you posted is the page of the openni-contest within which RGB-D SLAM was first introduced. The second link is the wiki page of the RGB-D SLAM package that came out of it.

Also note the disclaimer on http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/RGBD-6D-SLAM :

**This page describes the software package that we submitted for the ROS 3D challenge.** [The current RGBD-SLAM package is located here.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-09-23**:
Correct